# Add and remove CssClass ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a weird behavior with my ASP.NET application. I want to change the color of the current selected row in a Grid View.

My GridView is defined like this :

```
<asp:GridView [..] OnSelectedIndexChanged="SUPResultList_SelectedIndexChanged">
    [..]
    <RowStyle CssClass="DataGridItem" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="DataGridAlternateItem" />
</asp:GridView>
```

In my code-behind, I have :

```
protected void SUPResultList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = sender as GridView;

    // I remove the class "selected" from the older row
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
    {
        row.CssClass = row.CssClass.Replace("AdminRowSelected", String.Empty);
    }

    grid.SelectedRow.CssClass = String.Join(" ", grid.SelectedRow.CssClass, "AdminRowSelected");
}
```

May be there is a better way to do what I want ?

Anyway, when my gridview is first rendered, my rows have the good classes. But when I select a row and enter in SUPResultList_SelectedIndexChanged, row.CssClass is empty (so the result of row.CssClass.Replace("AdminRowSelected", String.Empty) is "" and String.Join(" ", grid.SelectedRow.CssClass, "AdminRowSelected"); is "AdminRowSelected"). After my processing I lose my original class and the rows become white (except the selected row).

I also tried this instead of my loop but it failed too :

```
grid.RowStyle.CssClass = "DataGridItem";
grid.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "DataGridAlternateItem";
```

Do you have an idea of what is happening (and how to correct it ^^) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You want to  change color of current selected row, but your code is handling alternating rows. The default properties of the grid should have the necessary code to handle current selected row. You may want to revert back to the default and compare.

Comment: First, I removed the class "AdminRowSelected" of all rows (to be sure that only one row will have the class) and then, with that line `grid.SelectedRow.CssClass = String.Join(" ", grid.SelectedRow.CssClass, "AdminRowSelected")` I set the good class with the good row.

Comment: But Garrison Neely answer the best way for doing that : use the SelectedRowStyle property (I missed it -_-)

Comment: That's what I meant. I believe `SelectedrowStyle` was there by default unless it's removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `SelectedRowStyle`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrowstyle.aspx

Comment: Ok, I missed that property. I'm going the strangle myself and I come back -_-.

Thanks !